# Cordova: can I display a native application component in a div?

Tags: ios, html, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I am considering using Cordova to build a mobile application. The main driver is that I want to be able to port my app to multiple platforms without having to re-write the presentation layer. I like Angular and jQuery Mobile which I feel can produce a good quality presentation with less effort when compared to developing multiple native presentation layers.

The caveat is that one component of the app is slightly more complex. I would like to leverage native SDKs to write this particular component and have it work seamlessly -- as an embedded sub-view -- with the rest of my app. I thought that I could solve this problem elegantly by writing a Cordova plug-in. Reading the documentation, I see how I can write a "headless" plug-in, or one that pops open in front of the web view overriding the display while it is active. But can I display a plug-in with a UI in a `<div>` within the web-app?

For example, let's suppose that my native component is the native "address book" view (in iOS, this module has a ViewController which renders its display). I would want to render it somewhere in a `<div>` in the page where I can still see my app header -- NOT have it pop open above my entire application until I complete my selection.

I see that it is possible to embed the CordovaWebView in a native app. But I want to know if the other way around is also possible.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out Frederic? I am facing a similar issue: http://stackoverflow.com/q/21767146/527559

Comment: Not in any straightforward manner, no

Answer (score 0):

As far as I am aware Cordova/PhoneGap does not allow native components inside the webview.

There is a plugin for accessing the devices contact list/address book [here](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-contacts). With this you can get a list of all contacts and insert them with your own UI into your app. It might be slightly more work but it should get the job done.

Answer (score 0):

You can use native components inside a webview, but you can't embed them inside a html element, that means, the native component will remain over the html.

With some work you can be able to make it fit in the div position, so it seems that it's inside the div, but if your html page have scroll it might be from very difficult to impossible to make the native view move with the scroll.