# How can I add a native view from a Cordova plugin

Tags: ios, cordova, phonegap-plugins, cordova-plugins

I am developing a plugin with the latest version of Cordova (3.3). I need to add a native `UIImageView` to the Cordova view.

If I have access to the project for example in the platform folder, I can add my view to the view instance belonging to `CDVViewController`. However, I am not sure how to access that reference from a plugin.

Inside my plugin I have:

```
@interface CDVCool : CDVPlugin

@property (weak, nonatomic) UIImageView *nativeImageView;
...
@end
```

How can I initialize and render this view by modifying only the plugin files?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Credit for this answer goes to [devgeeks](https://github.com/devgeeks) who pointed me to a couple of his plugins, [MapKit](https://github.com/imhotep/MapKit) and [VolumeSlider](https://github.com/devgeeks/VolumeSlider), that mix in native elements with cordova web view.

The key is to overwrite the `initWithWebView` method:

```
-(CDVPlugin*) initWithWebView:(UIWebView*)theWebView
{
    self = (VolumeSlider*)[super initWithWebView:theWebView];
    return self;
}
```

Now inside the plugin you can obtain a reference to the view controller behind cordova web view and add to it whatever your heart desire.

```
[self.webView.superview addSubview:mpCustomView];
```

This is cool becuase you can control the zPosition of any views you add with respect to the webView. So you can put views above or below the web view.

Comment: Note: in newer versions of Cordova, this needs to be done in `- (void)pluginInitialize`